Regulation around XVA for Commodity Firms
This is more of a Regulation topic than a pure Quant one.
The Basel Committee on Banking Supervision (BCBS) has formally recognized CVA by including its risk management as part of the Fundamental Review of the Trading Book. Banks are thus computing XVA through an XVA Desk generally.
There is nothing similar on the MiFID side, meaning Commodity Firms have no obligation to compute XVA. I am trying to understand whether it would nevertheless be profitable for them to compute XVA.
Is there any paper/study that you know about, which will present at least one of the following point:

Percentage of Commodity firms which are computing XVA
Benefits of doing so
Impact on PnL
Cost of creation of XVA Desk

Thanks
